# changing options in dropdown multiple select (selectList wirdget) dynamically

Tags: jquery, select, dynamic

i am desperately trying to get this work:

I habe two dropdown and the second is showing districts based on the chosen city in the first dropdown. I used the selectList-widget (http://odyniec.net/projects/selectlist/) for the second dropdown. It is working fine as long I defined the possible options static with . Now used the onchange function and load the disticts from the database. It is working with the standard multiple select item but not with the jQuery-widget. The problem that is not refreshing. Any idea how i can solve that problem.

The html code:

```
<select id="stadtteile" multiple="multiple" name="languages[]"
                title="Stadtteil(e)?">

'<option value="6001">Altstadt</option>';
'<option value="6002">Bahnhofsviertel</option>';

jQuery('select#stadtteile').selectList({ sort: true });
```

on change do the following:

```
jQuery('select#stadtteile').load("getdistricts.php?choice="+obj.value).val().appendTo(jQuery('#stadtteile'));
```

Any idea how to refresh the jQuery?

Also I got this error message:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'appendTo' of null

Comment: `.load` isn't going to work like that.

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution without php or plugins is to keep the districts in text files, one for each city (in the form `<option value = 'abc'>District_Name_1</option><option value = "bcd">District_Name_2</option>` and then to run something like this:

```
  $("#selector_2").load("[...]/txt/' + $(this).val() + '.txt");
```

The path to /txt must be on the same domain, and you may want to add a basic cachebust to the load function ot ensure you always get the latest version of the requested txt file.